# How to set key null in Dictinoary with `int?` in the key C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to set null into key that defined `int?`:

My code:

```
Dictionary<int?, string> dic=> Config.Where(a => a.Field == nameof(SafeFilesPath)).OrderBy(s => s.IndexOrder).ToDictionary(a => a.IndexOrder, b => b.Value);
```

`IndexOreder` can be also `null`.

And it fails.
I must this null-key.
What can I do???

I select all the parameters from DataBase. And the Keys can be also `NULL`.

Comment: What´s the point of having Dictionary with null keys?. Wouldn't that be a List<string>?

Comment: @NicoRiff: Because there are times there is a key and there are times when I want to have one key with `NULL`

Comment: @Ayal if the data comes from a database, `NULL` means there's no value, not a `NULL` value. You can't use `Where someField = NULL` in a database either. I'd question a database design where a key can be null in the first place. If you can't improve the query that loads those values, a good solution would be to use a magic value as vc74 suggested. I'd suggest `int.MinValue` though as database keys are typically positive numbers

Comment: @Ayal if you want to store unknown/missing/not-applicable entries in the database (eg in a lookup table or dimension table), use well-known values like -1 for `Missing`, -2 for `Not Applicable` etc

Comment: There is no option to put a NULL value ???
I want to put the values as they are! No magic values

Comment: The only thing you could do is wrap your `int?` into a custom class which stores the `int?` so something like `Dictionary<MagicInt, string> dic=> Config….ToDictionary(a => new MagicInt(a.IndexOrder), b => b.Value);` your custom class Needs to override Equals and GetHashCode.

Comment: Another idea - you could cast your `int` into `double` and use `double.NaN` as the null indicator. Like this: `Dictionary<double, string> dic=> Config….ToDictionary(a => (double?)a.IndexOrder ?? double.NaN, b => b.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

> As long as an object is used as a key in the Dictionary,
>   it must not change in any way that affects its hash value. Every key
>   in a Dictionary must be unique according to the
>   dictionary's equality comparer. A key cannot be null, but a value can
>   be, if the value type TValue is a reference type.

[Dictionary Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: But `int?` it's meen that you nullable, no?

Comment: @Ayal no. It means you have something that can *hold* nulls, but isn't null itself. What are you trying to do in the first place? Why not use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to check if a key exists?

Comment: Becouse I want to Insert one value with `NULL` in the key, I don't want `0`

Comment: I select the keys from the DataBase and it's can be also `null`

Comment: @Ayal update your question explaining what you want to do. Since you load data from the database you are probably using `ToDictionary`, not `Dictionary.Add`. Even in the database though you *can't* use a NULL as a key value, because you can't compare one null with another. `NULL` means `I don't know`.

Comment: I update the question